# Is it safe to change a class member variable's access specifier in the header file while keeping the dll associated with it unchanged?

Tags: visual-c++

I use c++ on Visual studio 2008.

I am using a 3rd party library (BCG) in my application. I need to make a change to the access specifier (from protected to public) of a BCG class' member variable. The question is: is it safe to change the access specifier only in the header file, which is included in my application, without regenerating the dll file? It is possible to do it, and on the surface, it seems to work fine. However I am not sure whether it is safe.

I am trying to derive from a class used in that third party library and in order to achieve what I want, I need to access a protected variable from another class. I want to have the least damaging change (for future integration) so I want to avoid changing the dll file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance member access doesn't involve any fix-up of symbols in the linker.  Instead, the identity of members compiles down to offsets against the object pointer, so name-mangling and other linkage questions don't enter into it.  This is why it seems to be working for you.

Modifying the headers describing classes that are published by a DLL you can't rebuild is obviously dangerous behavior, in general, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But I guess there's no case you can think of where this might break anything?

Comment: At a mechanical (compilation/linkage) level, no, but I guess I would note that the authors of the class never intended to make that variable available, so you should certainly never write to it and you should avoid making assumptions about how they are using it.